# Can I get measurable speed improvements by replacing Console.WriteLine with a logging framework?

Tags: .net, performance, logging

Currently, our C#, .Net 3.5 win app does quite a bit of `Console.WriteLine()` to keep 'soft' logs (not saved in files), which is both not entirely useful and probably a bit of a performance bottleneck, especially as its purpose is to do a bunch of calculations as quickly as possible.

I've just moved onto the team so I haven't had time to profile an average running time, but it seems to me that it must be improvable by replacing the console output with something that is

- optimised for speed
- configurable at runtime, i.e. *turnonandoffable*

Configuration is great, but I have no idea if there would be any improvement, or degradation, in performance by switching to an equivalent amount of logging through a framework (Log4Net or other).

My gut tells me that having the same logging to the same output might be *slightly* slower  in Log4Net as it's essentially doing the same thing but having to go through another library. Is this correct or does it take some shortcuts to speed things up?

I would also think that skipping the console and writing directly to a log file would be faster (no buffer flushing, etc), as well as being saved for review/audit/posterity - **so overall the best choice.**

Does my thinking make sense - is this something I can confidently propose to the team lead? The only way I can reliably test this is to implement it, of course, but I was hoping I could back up my initial suggestion with others' knowledge and experiences.

Comment: The console is *very* slow.  Made for human eyes, not loggers.  So yes, easy win.

Comment: It's *probably* a bottleneck? If you worry about performance, the first thing you should do is to **profile**, not guess what could be slow.

Comment: @svick this is very true. But repeated and unnecessary console I/O is a good candidate for causing slowdown, don't you think?

Comment: @Alex, it doesn't matter what I think. The only thing that matters is what your profiler says. I think trying to avoid unnecessary console IO could quite possibly be premature optimization.

Comment: @svick I'll keep that pitfall in mind and do some profiling first, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hesit to answer, since you've given my answers yourself, but I'm starving for rep :) ...

In my experience, Console logging is the slowest option of all. I often started with console logging and was always surprised how much faster the program run, when I turned it of. I think, that you won't even notice the (small) overhead of some intermediate framework, when you're logging to the console.

I usually found it much faster to write to a file and use a dedicated log viewer software to watch it (sorry, I don't have any software names at hand, but google should help you find a software).

There's also an option to use eg. [OutputDebugString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and a viewing utility (sorry, again, no name), if you want to watch your log during runtime.

And of course saving logfiles for post-runtime-analysis is something, you might no longer miss after you started using it.

The augmented configurability is of course a benefit, personally I do not make much use of it besides globally turning logging on and off (ok, sometimes, I use two or three different trace levels if I want some messages also appear in production code).

So I think, your guts are right and I would suggest switching to some framework asap :)

Just one remark:

> no buffer flushing, etc

I would strongly suggest, *not* to disable buffer flushing. I flush my log buffers after every message. In case of a program crash, you won't have any clues what went wrong, if you loose the last messages before the crash.

Comment: This is great, and a relief that I'm on the right track :) Agreed about the buffer flushing actually, I wouldn't like to see an entire run's log disappear because I wanted to skimp on a couple of milliseconds. Don't actually know what Log4Net does by default, though.

Comment: The API info for `TextWriterAppender.ImmediateFlush` (from which `FileAppender` inherits) says, that the default setting is to flush after every append (a wise decision :) ...). See here: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.TextWriterAppender.ImmediateFlush.html

Comment: Brill, thanks. "Indeed, when flushing is skipped, then it is likely that the last few log events will not be recorded on disk when the application exits. This is a high price to pay even for a 20% performance gain." Yeeeeah I think I'll leave the flushing on!

Comment: The phrase "always flush your logs" popped into my head and now I can't stop giggling.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, I agree with @Martin, but think a bit.
How many messages per second are being logged?

If it's in the hundreds or more, then getting rid of writing to the console might save a good fraction of time.

If you want to speed things up, you always need to think in terms of *what percent of time does something take*.

Comment: That's a good point. I'm not sure how much time is spent logging - as I said I'm a recent joiner to the team. But if I can save even 5-10% of time it may be worth a simple swap to log4net. Will have to do some profiling as @svick suggested.

Comment: @Alex: You could just time it with and without the Console stuff. (I take a dim view of profilers ;-)

Comment: I actually did a global comment-out of all the console stuff and it cut the running time by 25%. I'll probably still need at least some of that logging though so it won't be such a dramatic gain, but still, that's a good start :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to add a brief example, as we had a very similar issue and this info might be of interest.

In our app we make heavy use of Log4Net. By profiling the app, we realised that the ILog.Log methods were taking an inordinate amount of time. Essentially every Logging call was a blocking call that wrote a single line to a text file. A simple change in the configuration, swapping out the `RollingFileAppender` to a custom `BufferedFileAppender` improved performance dramatically in our application. Unbelievably, some operations that involved heavy logging and previously took several seconds were down to sub-second times after making this switch.

The BufferedFileAppender essentially batches a number of log messages at once by queueing log messages and performing fewer file writes. This ensures that ILog.Log acts like an asynchronous call (in terms of performance), but also ensures deterministic ordered processing of log messages.

I would imagine in your case the Console.WriteLine is blocking - what you ideally need to do is batch operations and write 100x lines at a time (or say every 100ms write whatever lines have been buffered). A simple wrapper class around Console.WriteLine could be written to acheive this.

Comment: Ideally, yes - have just seen that Log4Net provides a BufferingAppenderSkeleton, which looks useful. I suppose it will depend on profiling again, but I'll definitely keep this in mind.

Comment: FYI by writing this yourself you could implement a nice queue and asynchronous write, then a separate thread pick up data from the queue to write to file. This would give you a good balance between performance and writing as soon as possible to the log, in order to get messages in the event of a crash.